# GetElementsByTagName leads to call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell, httpwebrequest, webrequest, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I'm working on a MacBook with VisualStudio.

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Code:

```
$requestSwiss = Invoke-WebRequest "https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial:Suche&limit=5000&offset=0&profile=default&search=Sanatorium&searchToken=9x3wgpsz3j9z6bchkew1du5if"

Write-Host $requestSwiss

($requestSwiss.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') | Where{ $_.className -eq 'mw-search-result-heading' } ).innerText
```

Any ideas? Also tried:

```
$test = $requestSwiss.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div')
foreach($object in $test) 
{ Write-Host $object }
```

exactly the same error.

The web request works fine. It prints the whole sourcecode from wikipedia.

Thanks

Comment: Make it a subexpression and see if that works better for you: `$($requestSwiss.ParsedHtml.getEle.....).Innertext`

Comment: Would a MacBook completely support Invoke-Webrequest in the first place? If I recall, Invoke-Webrequest uses IE to make all connections. It is so reliant that simply not opening IE for the first time before using Invoke-Webrequest will prevent it from working.

Comment: @ZachAlexander It was the Macbook indeed. But the Webrequest worked fine - it was the getElementsByTagName who didin't work on mac.

Comment: @Twinfriends That sucks. I guess you'll have to regex out what you want then.